# How to port gcnew and gcroot from Visual C++ to gcc

Tags: porting, gcc, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have the task to port some code from Visual C++ to gcc.
Some calls are `gcnew` and `gcroot` to handle managed code inside cpp module.
How can these calls be ported to gcc in a fashionable way?

Comment: A little bit more context, for example, what the managed code is about, or how much there is of it, would probably allow us to give you a better answer.

Comment: BTW you should not port to a new compiler, but to a more standard programming language (probably standard C++14). So switching from `g++` to  `clang` should be easy once you did your job.

Comment: Microsoft documentation on [C++/CLI (Common Language Infrastructure)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx). Basically, nothing in C++/CLI is portable. Many of the platform libraries are shared with C#, so porting the application to C# might be possible if the target OS is Windows. C++/CLI itself is confined to Windows on x86 or x64 CPUs. Porting to a different GUI framework typically requires complete re-architecting of the GUI part of code. C++/CLI might use GUI such as: System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).

Comment: Porting the GUI code to Xamarin (Mono, an environment that uses C# language) might allow it to run on platforms other than Windows x86/x64. Data can be passed between C# and plain C++ (which may be compiled as unmanaged DLL on Windows or dynamic shared object (.so) on Linux) using P/Invoke, available on both Microsoft C# and Xamarin/Mono.

Answer (score 7):

Those calls can't be ported, at least not directly. `gcnew` is not a C++ keyword, it is from "C++/CLI", which is a different language currently not supported by gcc. [This older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363745/gcc-support-for-c-cli) says there was once an attempt to support it, but it seems to be dead since 2009.

The only reasonable way for this is to port all of the the managed code to standard C++, then `gcnew` and `gcroot` won't be needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [DocBrown's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/367270/40065), you could consider using some existing garbage collector library (e.g. [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), or [RavenBrook's MPS](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/), or your own GC) in your code. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019003/841108).

It might not be easy to use such a GC (it might not even worth the pain, and you could decide to use genuine C++ manual management and smart pointers without any GC), and you certainly need to be aware of GC techniques, concepts, terminology and pitfalls. So read [*The GC handbook*](http://gchandbook.org/).

Notice that you might also consider using some existing C++ framework libraries, such as [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Boost](http://boost.org/).

You basically should rewrite your code to more standard C++ (e.g. C++14 at least).

Comment: Side note: when porting managed code to unmanaged, the missing GC is most often not the biggest issue, if it is an issue at all. Find a replacement for the .NET framework class libraries used by the program is.